# Easy implementation of Java org.w3c.dom.Element

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb, w3c

I want to create a custom Element which i can add to document while marshalling. The java org.w3c.dom.Element interface has so many methods, i am not sure how to implement them. Is there any util or any reference to help implementing a new element ?

Comment: I would not recommend doing that, those interfaces are quite difficult to implement correctly. You might rethink what your trying to do and what tools are available to help you achieve that.

Comment: okay, agreed. chose to modify the xml directly. thx